# On a convergence of a series of functions exercise $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{n}} \ln \Big(1+ \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{n}} \Big)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to study the various types of convergence of the series of functions $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{n}} \ln \Big(1+ \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{n}} \Big)$$

for $x \in R$.

So far I thought of doing the following:

$\ln(1+x^2 / \sqrt{n}) = x^2 / \sqrt{n} + x^4 / n + o(1/n)$

Then I have $$\frac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{n}} \ln \Big(1+ \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{n}} \Big) = \frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{{n}}+ \frac{x^{2(n+2)}}{n^{3/2}} + \frac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{n}}o(1/n)$$

But then I am a bit stuck, is this way a possibility? how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly if $|x|>1$ the general term of the series does not tend to zero, so the series is divergent. The only interesting case is therefore when $|x|=1$. In that case your analysis shows that the general term is of the order of magnitude of $1/n$, and consequently the series diverges in this case too. For $|x|<1$, however, the series converges, just apply your favourite convergence-test.

Comment: "The only interesting case" comes too early. I'd put it after $|x|<1.$ Also $O(1/n)$ is not what you want there; you want to say $\Theta(1/n)$ or something.

Comment: @zhw thank you both for your answers, could you explain a bit what is the difference between $O(1/n)$ and $\Theta(1/n)$? I have not seen the notation.

Comment: $f(n) = \Theta (g(n))$ means $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and vice versa. I think in analysis we would usually say $ f(n)$ is on the order of $g(n).$ I think $\Theta$ is used in computer science more.